# Find where handle is stored in scope

Tags: matlab, oop

MATLAB handle class objects are [deleted when they go out of scope](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/handle-class-destructors.html#btavjj2-1). I have objects that can be reused in different parts of an application, but which I want to destroy when they are no longer used anywhere. MATLAB's built in lifecycle behaviour allows me to do this without maintaining any additional global list to keep track of what might be using that object.

However I have a situation where an object I *think* should have gone out of scope is still firing event listener callbacks that are deleted as part of the object's destructor. I know where I think the last handle to this object in existence should have been stored, and sure enough when I check there that handle has been cleared. So there must be instances of this handle in scope somewhere else.

My application is a complex network of objects stored as properties of other objects. Is there anything I can do to help track down where in scope the handle to this object is being stored?

## Example

First set up a handle class with an event to listen to:

```
classdef Yard < handle
    events
        RollCall
    end
end
```

Then a handle class that reacts to `RollCall` events from a `Yard` object by displaying some text and then notifying its own event:

```
classdef Kennel < handle
    properties
        id
        yardListener
    end

    events
        RollCall
    end

    methods
        function obj = Kennel(yard,id)
            obj.yardListener = event.listener(yard,'RollCall',@obj.Report);
            obj.id = id;
        end

        function Report(obj,~,~)
            fprintf('Kennel %d is in the yard\n', obj.id);
            notify(obj,'RollCall');
        end
    end
end
```

And finally a class that reacts to `RollCall` events from a `Kennel` object by displaying some text:

```
classdef Dog
    properties
        name
        kennel
        kennelListener
    end

    methods
        function obj = Dog(name,kennel)
            obj.name = name;
            obj.kennel = kennel;
            obj.kennelListener = event.listener(kennel,'RollCall',@obj.Report);
        end

        function Report(obj,kennel,~)
            fprintf('%s is in kennel %d\n', obj.name, kennel.id);
        end
    end 
end
```

Now add some instances of these classes to the workspace:

```
Y = Yard;
% Construct two Dog objects, in each case constructing a new Kennel object to pass to the constructor
dogs = [Dog('Fido',Kennel(Y,1)) Dog('Rex',Kennel(Y,2))];
% Construct a third Dog, reusing the Kennel object assigned to dog(1)
dogs(3) = Dog('Rover',dogs(1).kennel);
```

I now have two `Kennel` objects in scope, with handles referenced in the properties of the `Dog` objects in the array `dogs`. Calling `notify(Y,'RollCall')` produces the following output:

```
Kennel 2 is in the yard
Rex is in kennel 2
Kennel 1 is in the yard
Rover is in kennel 1
Fido is in kennel 1
```

If the original two `Dog`s are deleted then kennel 2 goes out of scope but kennel 1 remains active since it is still referenced by the remaining `Dog`:

```
>> dogs = dogs(3);
>> notify(Y,'RollCall')
```

```
Kennel 1 is in the yard
Rover is in kennel 1
```

However if I hide an additional handle to kennel 1 somewhere else in scope before deleting the remaining `Dog` then it will remain active:

```
>> t = timer('UserData',dogs(1).kennel);
>> clear dogs
>> notify(Y,'RollCall')
```

```
Kennel 1 is in the yard
```

The question is if I don't know where or when this extra reference was created and why it hasn't been deleted, what can I do to debug the existence of the object?

Comment: Are you talking exclusively about graphical handles? If so, this could be a good place to start: `A = findall(0);` or `B = findobj;`.

Comment: Have you tried explicitly destructing your objects rather than relying on MATLAB to do it for you? This is a question that would be well served by a [mcve].

Comment: @Dev-iL - no, I'm talking exclusively about handles for objects of user-defined classes unfortunately. A `findall` analogy for other handle-class objects would be ideal.

Comment: @excaza - to decide to explicitly destroy an object, I have to know that nothing in the application state has any need for it. Attaching lifecycle to presence in scope is in many senses a perfect solution to that, and requiring the entire code base to maintain some centralised list which is then responsible for explicit object destruction is tantamount to creating a parallel model of MATLAB's framework for workspaces in the function call stack. My question addresses whether MATLAB's built in functionality is able to solve my problem *without* extending it at such a low level...

Comment: ...@excaza this may indeed be better explained with an MCV, however, which I will try to put together in the next couple of days.

Comment: So if there was some way to list _all_ variables in MATLAB's memory, along with who references them, then test their class to see if they're an instance of `some_user_defined_class` - it would solve your problem, yes?

Comment: @Dev-iL that would definitely help. I do however have a handle to the exact instance of the class in question, since I'm discovering that it still exists when an event listener embedded in the object is fired. This passes the object as an argument to the callback, so now I obviously have a second handle in scope, but just need to test where else the same handle is stored - even just what workspace in the function call stack would help.

Comment: Is modifying the classes you're using an option? If so, a hack comes to mind where you maintain your own "stack memory".. If you inherit everywhere additionally from a class that has almost nothing but a "static field" (this can be implemented with `persistent` variables) containing a list that gets written-to during each object's construction (with details on who created it, on which line, etc. using the info in `dbstack`), you might be able to view this list when needed to see where there are more references.. I hope the general idea is clear. Please excuse my brevity :)

Comment: Circumstances of the object construction are easy to identify in my case - it's where copies of the object's handle get to after construction that needs debugging. The hack you suggest is a handy one to bear in mind but I don't think it can be applied here unless objects can be made aware of when their handles are being copied and passed around.

Comment: @excaza - created an MCV; hope it helps

Comment: @Will is there anywhere you store the handle that MATLAB might not notice when it is out of scope?  For instance, if the Dog class contained a list of kennel handles ever associated with that dog, then when you cleared the dogs, MATLAB would have to walk the kennel list inside each dog to see which handles were not being used.  In the example you give, the handle for kennel 2 that goes out of scope is part of the Dog classdef, so that is easy for MATLAB to notice.  Worse still, what if that kennel list I just suggested was instead a list of objects that had lists of kennels inside of them.

Comment: @Will have you tried adding your own ref counters when handles are being used?  So the constructor of Dog would call the AddRef function of Kennel twice and the constructor of Kennel would call the Yard AddRef once.  When you assign `dogs =` or `dogs(3) =` you would add to your code a call to the AddRef for each Dog.  When you assign `dog = dogs(3)`, you would call the AddRef for `dogs(3)` and RemRef for all three dogs.  The Dog RemRef would decrement its counter and twice call the Kennel RemRef, which would call Yard RemRef. At any point you can print all the reference counters from Yard.

Comment: @DanielWisehart I'm not sure exactly how MATLAB keeps track of references for the purposes of lifecycle but I'm primarily assuming that it's doing so properly. The documentation implies MATLAB notices and treats cycles of references the same as a single reference from an object going out of scope, and I should therefore always be able to locate a variable containing the reference if I know where to look. Knowing the location is valuable debugging information as it narrows down which parts of a complex code base could be leaving the reference there, and hence helps figure out why.

Comment: @DanielWisehart On that basis I don't see how keeping a reference count would help either. This would simply shift the problem to explaining why the ref count was not zero. One could perhaps maintain a list of back-references to objects which want to keep the object in scope, rather than just a count, but this is rather limiting. Handles are not just stored in handle-class objects, and many of the handle-class objects that do store them are builtin ones like event listeners that would be difficult to extend.

Comment: I hear you @Will but it is place to start.  For event listeners I would ref count  handing them a handle (and what you think would free that handle) and start with the assumption that MATLAB does not have a reference leak.  Once you know exactly which handle is being held--is it always the same one?--it may lead you to the problem--something you do once, for instance.

Comment: If a count alone does not do it @Will, add a list of function names to the reference count so that each add fills in which function added the reference and where the handle was expected to be freed, while the remove fills in the function that removed it.  Dump the full list of function name adds and deletes before program exit and post process it to find out where your extra add is coming from.

Answer (score 2):

This is something I have dealt with a lot. You see, clearing the handle object variable in one scope will not trigger the destructor if there is still a reference to the object in any other scope. If you explicitly called the destructor for the `Dog` and `Kennel` objects, your timer object would have a reference to an invalid object.

In the constructor for `Dog` there is an event listener created, whose destructor is never called which retains a reference to an instance of `Dog`.

I would implement a delete function for `Dog` and `Kennel` which called 
the delete function for the listeners. Here is a coding pattern I use a lot.

```
classdef MyClass < handle
   properties 
      listener % listeners are themselves handle objects
   end
   methods
      %% Class constructor creates a listener 
      %% Class methods
      function delete(obj)
         % do this for all handle object properties
         % Also, avoid calling constructors for handle objects in
         % the properties block. That can create references to handle
         % objects which can only be cleared by a restart
         if ishandle(obj.listener)
            delete(obj.listener)
         end
      end
   end
end
```

In the example you gave, you created a `timer` object which also maintains a reference to your `dogs` object. Clearing `dogs` does not eliminate this reference. Neither would clearing the `timer` object. You must explicitly delete `timer` objects.

I use `handle` objects a lot, and usually design GUI`s to go with them (aside, never, never, never use GUIDE for this. It is the worst thing ever). You have to be sure to clear all references to any`handle`objects called in your code. I do this by setting the`'DeleteFcn'` callback on the graphics handle object that contains the GUI (could be a figure, uicontainer, uipanel, etc.). I include this example because it illustrates how carefully references to handle objects need to be maintained.

function dispGUI(handleOBJ,hg)

```
  %% build gui in hg
  set(hg,'DeleteFcn',@deleteCallBack)
  h  = uicontrol(hg,'Callback',@myCallback)
  function myCallback(h,varargin)
     % So now there is a reference to handleOBJ
     % It will persist forever, even if cleared in the caller's
     % workspace, thus we clear it when the containing graphics 
     % object delete callback is triggered.
     if isvalid(handleOBJ)
        set(h,'string','valid')
     else
        set(h,'string','invalid')
     end
  end


  function deleteCallBack(varargin)
     % calling clear on handleOBJ clears it from the scope of the 
     % GUI function
     % also call clear on the containing function
     clear handleOBJ
     clear(mfilename)
  end
```

end

Another issue I have noticed with `handle` class objects, is that if you modify and save their `classdef` file while there are live references to these objects you can occasionally get into a situation where there are references to the object that you can only clear by resetting Matlab.